# How to get two largest pictures in the same page

Tags: floats

Good afternoon !

I'm searching a way to add two largest pictures in the same page. The page will contain only those pictures with their titles :

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=0.3in,right=0.3in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{center}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{../figures/figures2/res1.png}}}
\end{center}
\caption{Convergence performance plots of the conceived hybrid optimizer based on iterations number : part-1}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier


\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{center}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{../figures/figures2/res2.png}}}
\end{center}
\caption{Convergence performance plots of the conceived hybrid optimizer based on iterations number : part-2}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier


\end{document}
```

The used pictures are the following :
[image: res1]
[image: res2]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If they fit, you can put two captions in one figure.  Use [p] to fill the entire page.  There are size restrictions with all other float types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page will support two figures almost half the height of the `textheight`  (due to the space required for the captions).

I simplified your code and used test figures from the `graphicx` package: a square and a rectangular shape.

Since you obviously want to keep the aspect ratio of both figures and the same expansion factor for both, there is only one degree of freedom: the percentage of the text height assigned to both figures. (0.45 in the example, but it might be different in your case).

Using the [H] of the package `float` will induce LaTeX to keep the figures in the right place. I added some dummy text to a first page to illustrate how it works.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=0.3in,right=0.3in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{float} % needed <<<<

\usepackage{showframe} % show the text area
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text


\begin{document}

\kant[1]
\newpage

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \caption{Convergence performance plots of the conceived hybrid optimizer based on iterations number : part-1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Convergence performance plots of the conceived hybrid optimizer based on iterations number : part-2}
\end{figure}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works well ! Thank you a lot sir for your help !

Answer (score 2):

A quick test (starting with Simon's solution) showed that you can use `[p]` instead of `[H]` if you add a `\clearpage` after instead of a `\newpage` before.  This is, after all, what the [p] float type is for.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=0.3in,right=0.3in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{float} % needed <<<<

\usepackage{showframe} % show the text area
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text


\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \caption{Convergence performance plots of the conceived hybrid optimizer based on iterations number : part-1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Convergence performance plots of the conceived hybrid optimizer based on iterations number : part-2}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your remark !